# Loading subscription slow in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2014

I have a SQL Server 2014 test box with SSRS installed. The site loads ok and reports are quick. When I try to go to Subscribe the page takes over a minute to load. From there if I pick a schedule it also takes minutes to load. This is a fresh box with nothing else installed. There's not antivirus installed.

The box has 2 x xeon @ 2.66 and 6GB of memory. I'm the only user on this box as it is just for testing.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to improving the speed here? We're deploying SSRS 2016 in native mode and the page to manage subscriptions is painfully slow (and we only have a dozen or so subscriptions set up at this point).

Comment: @SqlRyan Unfortunately no.

Comment: That's too bad - the subscription page takes upwards of 5-6 seconds to load and there are virtually no subscriptions on the server yet since we're still pre-deployment. I suppose it says something that there's a $700 third-party product on the market specifically design to help you manage and update SSRS subscriptions...

Comment: We have SSRS 2016 and it takes 10 minutes when Editing a subscription (the only one)... what on earth is going on

Comment: @Pepys - -  I have the same exact issue. Have you managed to resolve it ?

Comment: @Halt_And_Catch_Fire not working with this now ;)

Answer (score -1):

This may be too late but try looking at the File settings for ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB, just like you normally would through SSMS on the instance. They may be defaulted to a few MB with a 1MB autogrowth.